# OR/AND in Google Drive search terms?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-search

I can imagine situations where it would be really nice to be able to use complex conditions on Google Drive searches. Is it possible to OR and AND search terms?

Right now, I'd like to search on Google Drive for a document with several possible owners. I have a personal Google account as well as on for work and I sometimes create a document using the "wrong" account. When I do this share the document with my alter ego. However, this means that I can't do a simple search using `owner` because my "other self" might be the owner.

So, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

`owner:me@work.com OR owner:me@home.com`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
owner:me@work.com OR owner:me@home.com
```

use

```
owner:(me@work.com|me@home.com)
```